# AWS Cognito and Private Access key in the app

Tags: android, authentication, key, amazon-cognito

I read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html):

> You have a mobile app. Do not embed an access key with the app, even
>   in encrypted storage. Instead, use Amazon Cognito to manage user
>   identity in your app

I want to understand something. If I use Unauthenticated Identities in Cognito AWS, is it the same like embed an access key with the app, because anyone with internet access can be granted AWS credentials?

> Enabling this option means
>   that anyone with internet access can be granted AWS credentials.
>   Unauthenticated identities are typically users who do not log in to
>   your application. Typically, the permissions that you assign for
>   unauthenticated identities should be more restrictive than those for
>   authenticated identities.

Can somebody explain what is difference between **embed an access key with the app** and **use Cognito for unauthenticated Identities**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain them clearly.

If you hard code your Access Key ID, Secret Access Key and Session Token, it means that you are embedding highly sensitive data in your application. An example of this is as follows:

```
AwsSessionCredentials awsCreds = AwsSessionCredentials.create(
    "your_access_key_id_here",
    "your_secret_key_id_here",
    "your_session_token_here");
```

Cognito Identity Pools are used to generate temporary AWS Access Key IDs, Secret Access Keys, and Session Tokens. This is returned by the [GetId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html) and [GetCredentialsForIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html) API calls. They are unsigned(non-SigV4 signed) API calls, and you can retrieve temporary AWS credentials without specifying a logins parameter map as an argument in the API call.

It is a recommended practice to use Cognito Identity Pool API calls(which are vended by AWS STS), instead of hard-coding sensitive data, as every application may be prone to reverse engineering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand something. If all my Access Key ID, Secret Access Key and Session Token belong to IAM user "XXX" with very limited permissions (let's say only read from S3), why it is more sensitive than unauthenticated identities in Cognito? It looks like the same level of sensitivity of data.

Comment: As a developer, I can attest to the fact that having any kind of hardcoded strings in production code is **not** a good practice. Even if your credentials with limited privileges(quoting your example, read-only from AWS S3) get exposed, it can still be deleterious for your AWS account's billing and usage. Every AWS API has API limits, and a potential breach can result in your API limits hitting their limits. To avert such a scenario, using Cognito Identity Pools to get temporary AWS credentials makes the flow infinitely more secure.